# An item with the same key has already been added - csvreader.fieldcount

Tags: vb.net, csv

I'm trying to create an import program from CSV.

My code is

```
csv = New CsvReader(New StreamReader("CSVFileLocation"), True)
Dim fieldCount As Integer = csv.FieldCount
```

The error message "An item with the same key has already been added." on the second line.
If I changed "HasReaders" to "False", there's no such error. But, I'm not able to get the Headers.

Could somebody help me on this, please?

FYI: I'm using Visual Studio 2010 version.

Regards,
Richard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check that your CSV file may have duplicate column names, or multiple empty cells, in the header row?

If that's the case, try to loop through your `csv` object, and try rename the headers in code before calling the property `FieldCount`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Sorry for my belated reply as I was on leave. Now, I could resolve the issue. It's because of the "Multiple Empty Cells" in CSV file. Regards, Richard

Comment: The "multiple empty cells" issue also occurs when the header row is missing entirely. The reader then tries to interpret your first line of data as column names. In my case I had several columns with a data value of "0" which was causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the `CsvReader` class is going through the first row adding strings to a dictionary, and the header row has two cells with the same value (so two identically named fields). Take a look at your data and see if this is the case. Alternately, if you have access to the source code for `CsvReader`, you could have it handle this case by naming the second field something slightly different (e.g., by appending a "1" onto the end of its name).

Comment: Source code available here - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader/CsvReader_src.zip